# InkPicture renders incorrectly when resized at specific Windows Display Scales

Tags: excel, vba, resize, userform, scaletransform

Using Excel/VBA I have made an Excel userform containing only an InkPicture control. I have managed to load a picture (Stretch mode), make the form resizable (API calls), resize the inkpicture upon resize. This is all working perfectly well.

I also need to resize the Ink manually, as it does not scale with the InkPicture. This should also be easily implemented with InkPicture1.Renderer.ScaleTransform and it works perfectly well - most of the time!

Problem: When resizing the userform the ScaleTransform function will stop scaling in either horizontal or vertical direction - but only at specific Windows Display Scales: 125%, 175%, 200% and 225% - whereas scaling 100%, 150% and 250% works perfectly.

The change of behavior at different Windows Display Scales is weird and I have looked for driver updates and performance bottlenecks.

I am uncertain if Display Scale only applies to touchscreens.

The have the same problem on both my computers:
- Microsoft Surface Pro 6 (i5), Windows 10, Office 365 - Excel 32bit
- Lenovo Yoga (i7), Windows 10, Office 365 - Excel 64bit.
Both are touchscreens, using onboard Intel Graphics. Running on external monitors makes no change.

I have investigated:
- Windows, Office and all Drivers should be up to date
- Disabling hardware acceleration (not applicable on my computers)
- Alternative code: using inkpicture.resize event instead
- Alternative code: ScaleTransforming one direction at a time

To reproduce the error you need to...
- Create a macro enabled workbook
- Create  UserForm (UserForm1)
- Add the InkPicture ActiveX control to the project
- Insert an InkPicture control (InkPicture1)
- Copy VBA code below into the project

Paste into module and run as macro:

```
Public Sub OpenUserForm1()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Paste into userform1 code:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DrawMenuBar Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long

Dim widthBefore As Double
Dim heightBefore As Double

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.InkPicture1.Top = 0
    Me.InkPicture1.Left = 0

    widthBefore = Me.InkPicture1.Width
    heightBefore = Me.InkPicture1.Height

    Call DrawForm
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Call MakeFormMaximizable
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Resize()
    Call DrawForm
End Sub

Private Sub DrawForm()
    If Me.InsideHeight = 0 Or Me.InsideWidth = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Me.InkPicture1.Width = Me.InsideWidth
    Me.InkPicture1.Height = Me.InsideHeight

    Dim hMultiplier As Single, vMultiplier As Single

    hMultiplier = Me.InkPicture1.Width / widthBefore
    vMultiplier = Me.InkPicture1.Height / heightBefore

    ' This function messes up!
    Me.InkPicture1.Renderer.ScaleTransform hMultiplier, vMultiplier

    widthBefore = Me.InkPicture1.Width
    heightBefore = Me.InkPicture1.Height
End Sub

Private Sub MakeFormMaximizable()
    Dim BitMask As LongPtr
    Dim Window_Handle As LongPtr
    Dim WindowStyle As LongPtr
    Dim Ret As LongPtr

    Const GWL_STYLE As Long = -16
    Const WS_THICKFRAME As Long = &H40000

    Const MAX_BOX As Long = &H10000
    Box_Type = MAX_BOX

    Window_Handle = GetForegroundWindow()
    WindowStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(Window_Handle, GWL_STYLE)

    BitMask = WindowStyle Or Box_Type Or WS_THICKFRAME

    Ret = SetWindowLongPtr(Window_Handle, GWL_STYLE, BitMask)
    Ret = DrawMenuBar(Window_Handle)
End Sub
```

To get Wanted/Expected behavior:
- Set Graphic Display Scale to 100% (followed by logout/login)
- Open Excel workbook / Open Userform
- Draw ink on userform
- Resizing the userform will be completely smooth and seamless - perfect!

To get Weird behavior:
- Set Graphic Display Scale to 200% (followed by logout/login)
- Open Excel workbook / Open Userform
- Draw ink on userform
- When resizing the userform the drawn ink no longer follows. It either only scales in one direction, or scales in a direction that is not being scaled.

I hope someone can reproduce the same error/behavior, has had similar experience, has an idea or ideally a fix.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around. You need to ignore the calculations the InkPicture Control makes on its Rendering Transform Matrix and instead use the Inkpicture.SetViewTransform and the InkTransform.SetTranform functions manually. The code is quite clear and now it will make your UserForm, InkPicture and your Ink resize coordinated and smoothly across all display settings (those tested anyways).

However, the scale factor will not be consistent across display settings - you need to calibrate the coordinate systems! I have done this by creating an initial scaling factor with the function Inkpicture.GetViewTransform. This needs to be called from Form_Init and I have wrapped the code in function GetInitScale in the code below.

Here is the full modified code except UserForm1.show:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLongPtr Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function DrawMenuBar Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function ReleaseDC Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "Gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Const HWND_DESKTOP As Long = 0
Const LOGPIXELSX As Long = 88
Const LOGPIXELSY As Long = 90
Const TWIPSPERINCH = 1440

Dim widthBefore As Double, heightBefore As Double
Dim xInitScale As Double, yInitScale As Double

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    widthBefore = Me.InkPicture1.Width
    heightBefore = Me.InkPicture1.Height

    Me.InkPicture1.Top = 0
    Me.InkPicture1.Left = 0

    Call GetInitScale

    Call DrawForm
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Call MakeFormMaximizable
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Resize()
    Call DrawForm
End Sub

Private Sub DrawForm()
    Me.InkPicture1.Width = Me.InsideWidth
    Me.InkPicture1.Height = Me.InsideHeight

    Call ScaleInk
End Sub

Private Sub GetInitScale()
    Dim aTransform As New InkTransform
    Dim eM11 As Single, eM12 As Single, eM21 As Single, eM22 As Single, eDx As Single, eDy As Single

    ' Remember initial transform to ensure robustness for diffrent display settings
    Me.InkPicture1.Renderer.GetViewTransform aTransform
    aTransform.GetTransform eM11, eM12, eM21, eM22, eDx, eDy

    xInitScale = eM11
    yInitScale = eM22
End Sub

Private Sub ScaleInk()
    Dim aTransform As New InkTransform
    Dim eM11 As Single, eM22 As Single

    ' Set transformation matrix manually
    eM11 = xInitScale * Me.InkPicture1.Width / widthBefore
    eM22 = yInitScale * Me.InkPicture1.Height / heightBefore

    ' Set new Transform
    aTransform.SetTransform eM11, 0, 0, eM22, 0, 0
    Me.InkPicture1.Renderer.SetViewTransform aTransform
End Sub

Private Sub MakeFormMaximizable()
    Dim BitMask As LongPtr
    Dim Window_Handle As LongPtr
    Dim WindowStyle As LongPtr
    Dim Ret As LongPtr

    Const GWL_STYLE As Long = -16
    Const WS_THICKFRAME As Long = &H40000

    Const MAX_BOX As Long = &H10000
    Box_Type = MAX_BOX

    Window_Handle = GetForegroundWindow()
    WindowStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(Window_Handle, GWL_STYLE)

    BitMask = WindowStyle Or Box_Type Or WS_THICKFRAME

    Ret = SetWindowLongPtr(Window_Handle, GWL_STYLE, BitMask)
    Ret = DrawMenuBar(Window_Handle)
End Sub
```

Hope this becomes useful to someone. It certainly was to me :-)

/Cheers